# Is it possible to create a new instance of the Windows Media Player class in VB 2008 code?

Tags: vb.net, windows-media-player

I don't want a Windows Media Player control on my form. I'm making an alarm clock. I have tried this:

```
Friend WithEvents WindowsMediaPlayer As New Microsoft.Win32.
```

But I don't see a Windows Media Player member.

Thank you.

I also asked on the [MSDN VB Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vblanguage/thread/1e54db2b-c987-49d3-8ccb-60f1400a6d49).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your snippet is not complete.  But nothing good will happen when you start with "Microsoft.Win32.".  Begin with Project + Add Reference, Browse tab and select c:\windows\system32\wmp.dll.  That adds a com interop wrapper with the namespace name "WMPLib".  IntelliSense will now spring to life and show you the classes in that namespace.  Make it resemble this:

```
Public Class Form1
  Friend WithEvents player As WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer

  Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    player = New WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer
  End Sub

  Private Sub player_StatusChange() Handles player.StatusChange
    ' A sample event handler...
  End Sub

End Class
```